# `maven war:war` makes webapp folder go inside of WEB-INF

Tags: maven

This is a test project structure.
There are `resources, java, webapp` folders inside of `src/main`. Default maven project, right?

[image]

And I need to export this project as `war` so tried `mvn war:war` on cmd.

But the unexpected result. the `images` folder, which is in the `webapp` folder, should be placed in the root of war, but it is in the `WEB-INF/classes`.

[image]

I don't get what is wrong. I didn't touch the `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maventest</groupId>
  <artifactId>maventest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maventest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <finalName>maventest</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: whatever you have in `src` will get bundled in `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: What you can do is have `WebContent` at the same level of `src` and inside `WebContent` you can have `images` and `WEB-INF` folders

Comment: @Ros5292 I followed your suggestion, but the `WebContent` was not bundled in the war

Comment: `WebContent` is now bundled, after I added `<warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>` inside of `maven-war-plugin`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are happy should I transform this into an answer  ?

Comment: Sure, why not. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating `WebContent` folder containing `images` and `WEB-INF` folders at the same level of `src` folder and bundle them into a war file.

Also as you mentioned, add below into `maven-war-plugin`

```
<warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
```